# syntax error in join operation

Tags: sql, ms-access, syntax-error

I am getting a syntax error in join operations: there are 2 different table with the same field names, but different field types. one is a autonumber the other is text field.  Here is my SQL.  could some one please help.

```
SELECT [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#], [Standard Brk].*, [Standard SubBrk].*
FROM ([SPO Data Entry Table] INNER JOIN [Standard Brk] ON [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#] = CDBL(Standard Brk.[SPO#]) 
INNER JOIN [Standard SubBrk] ON [Standard Brk].[Test #] = [Standard SubBrk].[Unit No]
WHERE [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#]=Val([Standard Brk].[SPO#]);
```

SPO Data Entry Table = autonumber
Standard Brk = text

Comment: Please add markup for your code - it'll be easier for others to read (and answer) your question.

Comment: What flavour of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: Based on the usage of `CDbl` and `Val`, plus the screwy table/field names, MS Access.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the table identifier around Standard Brk in your CDBL

you have `CDBL(Standard Brk.[SPO#])` it should be `CDBL([Standard Brk].[SPO#])`

also you haven't close the opening bracket straight after the from I'm guessing you need to add it straight after the closing bracket of `CDBL([Standard Brk].[SPO#])`

EDIT -=-=-= 
Reading the code further, drop the where clause too as it is the same as the inner join clause

Giving you

```
SELECT [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#], [Standard Brk].*, [Standard SubBrk].*
FROM ([SPO Data Entry Table] INNER JOIN [Standard Brk] ON [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#] = CDBL([Standard Brk.[SPO#]])) INNER JOIN [Standard SubBrk] ON [Standard Brk].[Test #] = [Standard SubBrk].[Unit No]
```

Comment: Not sure the Syntax error appears to be in the WHERE, When trying to run the query it is HIGHLIGHTED.

Comment: WHERE [SPO DataEntry Table].[SPO#])=Val([Standard Brk].[SPO#]); This is where my problem seems to be. Is it because these fields are different types and do I have to a WHERE clause?

Comment: @Dhoward: Delete the where clause it duplicates the inner join criteria

Comment: Help this is what I have now:   SELECT [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#], [Standard Brk].*, [Standard SubBrk].*
FROM ([SPO Data Entry Table] INNER JOIN [Standard Brk] ON [SPO Data Entry Table].[SPO#] = CDbl([Standard Brk.[SPO#]])) INNER JOIN [Standard SubBrk] ON [Standard Brk].[Test #] = [Standard SubBrk].[Unit No]   I am getting syntax error(missing operation)in query expression...What am I doing wrong?